# Remove item exactly once from list in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists, with corresponding values:

```
lists = [[7, 4, 7, 5, 3],
         [1, 3, 2], 
         [4, 5]]
vals = [7, 2, 5]
```

I would like to, in an efficient manner (runtime), remove the corresponding value in `vals`, from each list, exactly once. Eg, the first list `[7, 4, 7, 5, 3]` should become `[4, 7, 5, 3]` (or `[7, 4, 5, 3]`, ordering is unimportant).

**Expected output:**

```
[[4, 7, 5, 3], [1, 3], [4]]
```

**What I have tried:**

```
[lst.remove(val) for lst, val in zip(lists, vals)]
```

`list.remove(item)` removes the first occurrence of `item` in `list`, but since it returns `None`, the output becomes:

```
[None, None, None]
```

Any ideas on how to do this with a list comprehension (or other methods perhaps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're doing it in-place, I prefer to use a simple loop instead of a list comprehension and rebuilding a new item.

If you really want to have a different Python object (e.g: not in-place), you could keep this solution and `import copy`, to use `my_new_list = copy.deepcopy(lists)`. I think this is a cleaner way of doing it.

```py
lists = [[7, 4, 7, 5, 3],
         [1, 3, 2], 
         [4, 5]]
vals = [7, 2, 5]

for item, to_delete_once in zip(lists, vals):
    index = item.index(to_delete_once)
    if index != -1:
        _ = item.pop(index)

print(lists)
# [[4, 7, 5, 3], [1, 3], [4]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the `deepcopy` advice, I had to use that in my final version.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simple for-loop with `list.remove` is enough:

```
lists = [[7, 4, 7, 5, 3],
         [1, 3, 2], 
         [4, 5]]
vals = [7, 2, 5]

for l, v in zip(lists, vals):
    try:
        l.remove(v)
    except ValueError:
        pass

print(lists)
```

Prints:

```
[[4, 7, 5, 3], [1, 3], [4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, an alternative way without `remove` or `pop`:

```
new_lists = [ l[::-1][l.index(v):0:-1] + l[l.index(v)+1:] for l, v in zip(lists, vals)]
```

Not sure about the performance though, and for readability, I'd still go with an explicit loop.